# Chef cookbook recipe - executing windows batch command

Tags: ruby, jenkins, command, chef-infra, cookbook

I need help in writing chef recipes. I have some jobs in Jenkins and they are done by Execute Windows batch command. I have to rewrite this commands to chef recipe but I can't become familiar with writing these recipes... I need some example of this kind of "rewriting".

For instance, this command:

```
D: && cd D:\[some path] && pc.exe "\\[some folder]" -u "admin" -p [pass] cmd /c "c: && cd C:\some folders]\ && install.bat"
```

need to be rewrite to chef reciepe.
I can show other commands if it is needed.

I would by grateful to all kind of help

Comment: "but I can't become familiar with writing these recipes..." <- ??? Are you saying you don't want to learn and asking for someone else to do the job for you ?

Comment: No. I mean that I'm beginner with writing recipes. I read documentation, I have basic theoretical knowlege but I have problems with practical use. I have command and I have to convert it to chef recipe, I have a lots of commands like this. Here I am asking for one example how to do this, not doing my job by somone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the line:

```
execute "install" do
  command %Q{pc.exe "\\[some folder]" -u "admin" -p [pass] cmd /c "cd /D C:\some folders] && install.bat"}
  cwd "d:\[some path]"
end
```

should do. 
Without any insight on what does this command at all, it's hard to give a better advice, as for the placeholders, using attributes should be the way to go, but it's hard to tell without an entry point.

More details [in the documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html)